# Login and redirect customer to his website

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, login, session

In a mutistore-multiwebsite Magento, I'd like to force users to login to the same website they have registered. They might use any login form, in any website, but the form should check their credentials and redirect them to the correct website.

I tried to check the customer's website, and force him to login. It's not working quite good though. The user gets logged in to the current website, not the one he's registered.

In app/code/local/mage/Customer/Session.php

```
public function login($username, $password)
{
    /**************************************************/
    $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
    $customer_website = null;


    foreach (Mage::app()->getWebsites() as $website) {
        $customer->setWebsiteId($website->getId());
        $customer->loadByEmail($username);
        //check if user exists
        if($customer->getName()){
            $customer_website = $website->getId();
        }
    }
    /*************************************************/
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId($customer_website);

    if ($customer->authenticate($username, $password)) {
        $this->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you login from one site then automatically login at our site?

Comment: I'm not sure if understand your question. The user should be logged in and redirect to the website he's registered. Not both websites

Comment: Suppose, customer register at  Website A. Customer Have  try login from Website B,Then customer should redirect to WebsiteA with qutologin at websiteA. right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 10):

First,you need to do some changes in setting.

### Share customer accounts between multiple Website

You should configure this feature here: ***`System -> Configuration -> Customer Configuration -> Share Customer Accounts`***.

Make this setting to **Global** for *sharing every customer  to all websites*.

[image]

### Share login between websites

To keep the session when switching between stores **on different website**, enable "Use SID on Frontend" in *System > Configuration > General > Web*:

[image]

### Force users to redirect to the same website they have registered

Forcefully customer login *to the same website they have registered* when we have tried to login from another website.

Use `customer_login`

**Define event to config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Stackexchange_Magento165528>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Stackexchange_Magento165528>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <magento165528>
        <class>Stackexchange_Magento165528_Model</class>
      </magento165528>
    </models>
    <events>
      <customer_login> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <customer_login_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>magento165528/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>redirectoSourceDomain</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </customer_login_handler>
        </observers>
      </customer_login>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

**Observer class:**

```
<?php
class Stackexchange_Magento165528_Model_Observer
{

    public function redirectoSourceDomain(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $_customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        /* 
        * Store of website from which website  Customer have registered
        */
        $_customer_resgister_store_id= $_customer->getStoreId();
        
        if($_customer_resgister_store_id != Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId()){
            $allStores=Mage::app()->getStores(); //get list of all stores,websites
            
            foreach ($allStores as $_eachStoreId => $val){
                $_storeId = Mage::app()->getStore($_eachStoreId)->getId();
                //get url using store id
                if($_customer_resgister_store_id  == $_eachStoreId ){
                $Websiteurl= Mage::app()->getStore($_storeId)->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);
                $_redirecUrl =  $Websiteurl."customer/account/login?SID=".Mage::getModel("core/session")->getEncryptedSessionId(); 
                /* Force redirect to repective Website */
                Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
                            ->setRedirect($_redirecUrl)
                            ->sendResponse();
                        exit;   
                }

            }
            
        }
        return;
    }
        
}
```

**NOTE:**

*I HAVE TEST THIS CODE  on MY  MAGENTO DEMO STORE WEBSITES.*

- http://stackoverflow.amitbera.com
- http://m1.amitbera.com

This two website is running from same magento instance using website concept .

[image]

Comment: This is a correct way to handle this problem. But with this method, a customer in Website A can place an order in Website B. It can be a restriction from the project specification.

Comment: right, it depends on project specification

Comment: Is it possible to prevent customers from ordering from another website. This is a retail/wholesale multistore configuration, so retail customers should not be allowed to login to wholesale website

Comment: yes, it possiable

Comment: I have  few question?. how  you define a  customer  is retailer or wholesaler?

Comment: Only  want prevent login also registration?

Comment: A customer is defined as wholesaler/retailer, based on the website he's been registered.

Comment: Can wholesale/retailer customer register from both website

Answer (score 1):

you can rewrite below method for your requirment

rewrite below class

`Mage_Customer_Model_Session` `setCustomerAsLoggedIn` method

```
public function setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer)
{
    $this->setCustomer($customer);
    $this->renewSession();
    Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_login', array('customer'=>$customer));
    // check here customer website ID and redirect to their own registered website  
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that I should place the code i posted in setCustomerAsLoggedIn(), instead  of login()? Post a more detailed answer please.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `customer_login` event to avoid changing/rewriting/overriding core files.

In your config.xml

```
<config>
  <global>
    <models>
        ....
    </models>
    <events>
        <customer_login>
            <observers>
                <yourobservername>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>yourmodule/path_to_class</class>
                    <method>loginSwitchStore</method>
                </yourobservername>
            </observers>
        </customer_login>    
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

Your observer class (`/app/code/local/YourCompany/YourModule/Model/Observer.php`):

```
class YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Observer
{
    public function loginSwitchStore($observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();

        switch($customer->getCustomerGroup())
        {
            case 1: $storeCode = 'storeview1';break;
            case 2: $storeCode = 'storeview2';break;
            case 3: $storeCode = 'storeview3';break;
        }
        $params = array( '_current' => TRUE, '_use_rewrite' => TRUE, '_store_to_url' => TRUE, '_store' => Mage::app()->getStore($storeCode)->getId() );  
        $url = Mage::getUrl('', $params); 
        Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);

        //add this if you want them to stay in that store even after logout
        Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('store', $storeCode); 
    }
}
```

Note that you will have to assign different customers groups to customers of different  store views.

You can also assign customer attibute and set them at during registration via hidden field in registration form instead of assigning customer groups.